# Julian date of timezone-aware timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, julian-date

Should the Julian date change depending on the original timestamp's time zone?

For example, do `2020-01-01 +00:00` and `2020-01-01 +05:45` have the same Julian Date?

pandas suggests they do:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01', tz='Europe/London').to_julian_date()
Out[2]: 2458849.5

In [3]: pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01', tz='Asia/Kathmandu').to_julian_date()
Out[3]: 2458849.5
```

Is this a bug in pandas?

Comment: Maybe this is what you want to know? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17176/do-julian-day-number-handle-timezone-offset

Answer (score 0):

It seems julian date implementation doesn't care about the timezone

```
>>> pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01').to_julian_date()
2458849.5

>>> pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01', tz='UTC').to_julian_date()
2458849.5

>>> pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01', tz='Europe/London').to_julian_date()
2458849.5

>>> pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01', tz='Asia/Kathmandu').to_julian_date()
2458849.5

>>> pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01', tz='Asia/Kathmandu').tz_localize(None).to_julian_date()
2458849.5
```

If you want to take timezone into account, you have to handle it yourself:

```
>>> pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01', tz='Asia/Kathmandu').tz_convert('UTC').to_julian_date()
2458849.2604166665
```

> Is it correct that pandas is ignoring tz here?

The method [`to_julian_date()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d711b1d2ff9ee2c3faf0e118535d3d6218886a9d/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx#L2511-L2542) ignore `tz`:

```
class Timestamp(_Timestamp):
    ...
    def to_julian_date(self) -> np.float64:
        ...
        year = self.year
        month = self.month
        day = self.day
        if month <= 2:
            year -= 1
            month += 12
        return (day +
                np.fix((153 * month - 457) / 5) +
                365 * year +
                np.floor(year / 4) -
                np.floor(year / 100) +
                np.floor(year / 400) +
                1721118.5 +
                (self.hour +
                 self.minute / 60.0 +
                 self.second / 3600.0 +
                 self.microsecond / 3600.0 / 1e+6 +
                 self.nanosecond / 3600.0 / 1e+9
                 ) / 24.0)
```

Comment: yeah so if my datetime is from a different time zone, then will it have the Julian Date as one with UTC time zone?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity. There is something strange. If you convert to UTC manually, the fraction changes!

Comment: "correctly" right, so is the pandas one incorrect?

Comment: yeah my question is - is it correct that pandas is ignoring `tz` here? If you don't know, that's fine :)

Comment: Now I'm sure, `tz` is ignored :-)

Comment: yes, we agree that pandas ignores it. I'm just asking - does anyone know if it's _correct_ for pandas to ignore it?